# How python 3 hash function is randomized

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, hash

The [hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) built-in function of python has evolved after 3.3 to randomize the seed of the hash, which involves that the hash will return different results between two runs:

> Note: By default, the **hash**() values of str, bytes and datetime
>   objects are “salted” with an unpredictable random value. Although they
>   remain constant within an individual Python process, they are not
>   predictable between repeated invocations of Python.

I would like to know more about this process of randomization. Is the seed based on a timestamp ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392076/2301450) answer may help.

Comment: You could always look into the source code.

Comment: Good point John, this is the first thing I did, but I have to say it is a non trivial task...