# What is the time complexity of this function that iterates through a list a creates a dictionary?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, analysis, space-complexity

I have a function that rearranges an input list in a certain way and returns the output list. I am confused about what the time and space complexity of the function will be. Below is the code:

```
def rearrange_list(inp_list):
    d = {}
    output_list = []
    for num in inp_list:
        if num in d:
            d[num] += 1
        else:
            d[num] = 0
            output_list.append(num)
    for k,v in d.items():
        if v > 0:
            for i in range(v):
                output_list.append(k)
    return output_list
```

This is my complexity analysis:

- **Time complexity:** O(n + m<sup>2</sup>) where n is length of the input list and m is the size of dictionary
- **Space complexity:** O(n) where n is the length of input list

The main confusion I have is should I consider iterating through the dictionary O(n) too since worst case we will have n items in the list, or should it be represent it by m like I did in my analysis since it can be anything from 0 to n?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your time and space complexity are both `Theta(n)`. While sometimes it can be useful for clarity to include terms in the time or space complexity that don't change the asymptotic value (a classic example being [string searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Classification_of_search_algorithms)), it doesn't make as much sense here.

While your claim of `O(n + m^2)` time complexity is technically correct as Big-O notation is an upper bound, you can show that `O(n)` is also an upper bound, since the dictionary has size at most `n` and we iterate over each key exactly once: there are `n` items read from input, at most `n` loop iterations for the dictionary, and `n` items appended to the output list.

If you wanted, you can calculate 'auxiliary' space required, which would be the amount of space needed but not counting the input or output arrays. Here, that would be `Theta(m)`. You should note, however, that such analyses are fairly uncommon: by assumption, unless specified otherwise, space complexity analysis will include the size of the output.

---

To address a common confusion about why the second loop is still linear time with many duplicate values, let's look at an example.

The lines in question are:

```py
for k, v in d.items():
    if v > 0:
        for i in range(v):
            output_list.append(k)
```

Suppose our input list was `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]` (ten elements total: seven '1's and three '2's).

Then our `dictionary.items()` (which has the count of each element, minus one) would look like: `[(key: 1, value: 6), (key: 2, value: 2)]` (it's not really stored as a Python list of tuples internally, but these are the full contents of the items view-object).

Let's walk through that second loop's operation, line by line:

```py
for k, v in [(key: 1, value: 6), (key: 2, value: 2)]: 
# On our first iteration, so k = 1, v = 6.

    if 6 > 0:                      # 1 operation
        for i in range(6):         # 6 operations
            output_list.append(1)  # 6 operations

# For the (k, v) pair of (1, 6), the inner-loop has run 6 times.
# Every time the inner-loop runs, the length of output_list
# increases by 1

# Second iteration of outer-loop runs again:
for k, v in [(key: 1, value: 6), (key: 2, value: 2)]: 
# On our second iteration, so k = 2, v = 2.

    if 2 > 0:                      # 1 operation
        for i in range(2):         # 2 operations
            output_list.append(2)  # 2 operations

# For the (k, v) pair of (1, 6), the inner loop has run 2 times.
# In total: 8 inner-loop iterations, and output_list has len 8
```

In informal complexity analysis, a 'standard' rule of thumb is that the run-time of a double-nested loop is often quadratic. This is because we're counting the total number of inner-loop iterations, for example

```py
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
```

as

```
(n inner-loops per outer-loop) * (n outer-loops) = n^2 inner-loops
```

This assumption shouldn't be applied when the number of inner-loop iterations varies dramatically based on the state of the outer-loop. In our example, the inner-loop iterations is `v`, which depends on the outer loop.

To find the runtime here, **we need a different way to count how many inner-loop iterations occur**. Luckily, we can do that: in each inner-loop iteration, we append an element to `output_list`.

Since the final length of `output_list` is `n`, we know that the inner-loop has executed at most `n` times (technically, it's executed exactly `n-m` times, since the output_list already has size `m` after the earlier dictionary-initializing loop has terminated). Instead of incorrectly multiplying this by `m`, the number of outer-loop iterations, we should instead add the inner and outer loop iterations for a runtime of `Theta(n+m)` which is `Theta(n)`.

---

**Addendum**: Comments have correctly pointed out that since Python dictionaries don't have an `O(1)` amortized worst-case lookup/insert time guarantee, so the first loop is, at best, `Omega(m*n)`. While Python uses [pseudo-random probing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010222/why-can-a-python-dict-have-multiple-keys-with-the-same-hash) on an open-addressing table, this only ensures good 'average' performance. Thanks to [Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy) for the highly informative discussion and corrections.

Unfortunately, while `O(1)` amortized worst-case lookup/insert hashing is possible, for example with [Cuckoo hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing), in practice this is significantly slower on average than what's currently used in most standard libraries, and is unlikely to change in the near future.

Comment: Hmm, them saying m^2 suggests that they're interested in the *true* worst case. And with bad keys, it *does* take quadratic time (or rather mn here).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful @kcsquared! Do we ignore that in worst case the list will have same number repeatedly, for example [1,1,1,1,1,1,1], and in the `for i in range(v):` part it will take quadratic time?

Comment: @newbie_coder Actually, the code is still linear in the worst case, even for [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]. The only theoretically possible quadratic behavior is in the first loop, in the extremely unlikely case that you're using very large integers that force hash-collisions to work against the Python dictionary's collision resolution. In the particular case you mention, you only iterate over the '1' key in the dictionary once: The code inside `for i in range(v):` will run exactly `7` times total over the whole algorithm.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks for bringing that up; I hadn't even considered that they might be referencing hash collision behavior. I think the `O(m^2)` confusion came from a mistaken assumption about `for i in range(v)`, since a double-nested for loop would *usually* imply quadratic time, but not here.

Comment: @KellyBundy But since you mentioned it, I did more reading and I'm still not sure whether or not that's feasible. If the elements are str or bytes, Python3.3+ uses [hash randomization](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) by default, since cybersecurity researchers previously showed that quadratic time hash collision DDOS attacks were possible. For int elements, it seems like that type of attack (which is extremely unlikely without trying) might still be possible? At any rate, using Cuckoo hashing can guarantee `O(n)`, but you're right about worst case.

Comment: Oh.... right, their comment here does make it look their m^2 meant the second part. To be clear: The "very large" integers causing collisions already start at 19 digits. Very large compared to real life numbers, very *small* compared to some things I've done with numbers in Python :-P

Comment: Yes, hash randomization isn't applied to ints. So for example `rearrange_list([(2**61-1)*i for i in range(10_000)])` already takes me 1.7 seconds and with 20_000 it takes me 7 seconds. But I agree with "extremely unlikely *without* trying".

Comment: Oh, on 32-bit Python, I think collisions actually start with 10-digit numbers already, as it seems to use 31 instead of 61 there. Not gonna install that just for testing this, though :-P

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks for that example, I'll test that out and see if I can isolate the slowdown from all hashes being equal from other factors, like the large size of the numbers. This is extremely interesting; you seem very knowledgeable here, and there's no apparent question on SO specifically about massive hash collision for ints in Python3+: There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23391899/16757174) and older posts. I think an SO question specifically about the implications of int hashes not being randomized would be very useful.

Comment: If you remove the `-1`, you get very slightly larger numbers, and time drops from 1.7 and 7 seconds to ~0.004 and ~0.008 seconds. The `2**61-1` is `sys.hash_info.modulus`, btw (at least on the typical CPython 64-bit install).

Comment: @kcsquared Thanks so much for editing and adding a lot more details to the already helpful answer! I really appreciate the in-depth analysis and it is extremely helpful to understand the overall complexity! It also makes it very clear on when a nested for loop does not take quadratic time.

Comment: And thanks @KellyBundy for initiating a very interesting discussion!

Answer (score 2):

Do a step by step breakdown of the algorithm:

1. First `for` loop (`for num in inp_list`).
   It simply iterates over the list, which takes `O(N)` time, and the dictionary has size `O(number of unique elements in list)`, which can be generalized as `O(N)` space (where `N` = length of list = max possible number of unique keys).
2. Second `for` loop (`for k,v in d.items()`).
   This iterates over the keys in dict, which are `O(number of unique elements in list)` in count.
3. Third `for` loop (`for i in range(v)`).
   Since summation of `v` would just be the count of duplicate elements in the list, it will have an upper bound of `O(N)`.

A better approximation of the algorithm should be `O(N)` time and space, rather than the proposed `O(n + m^2)`

Comment: Why define N in addition to the already defined n, even with the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

### Time complexity

You can divide the code into two parts.

**Part 1**

```
for num in inp_list:
    if num in d:
        d[num] += 1
    else:
        d[num] = 0
        output_list.append(num)
```

In the first line you iterate through `inp_list`, and in each iteration you call `if num in d`. What python does is searches through the keys of dictionary `d`, therefore the time complexity for this part is O(nm) where n is the size of `inp_list` and m is the size the number of unique values in `inp_list`.

**Part 2**

```
for k,v in d.items():
    if v > 0:
        for i in range(v):
            output_list.append(k)
```

In this part you iterate through the size of the dictionary in the first row which is O(m). I am ignoring the nested for loop since the loop can be replaced by the following:

```
output_list = output_list + [k] * v
```

Which happens in O(1)

In conclusion, the time complexity should be O(nm + m) = O (m(n+1)) = O(nm).

Nevertheless, since d is a dictionary, the key search takes O(1) instead of O(m) (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539367/python-dictionary-keys-in-complexity)), making the time complexity drop to O(n).

### Space complexity

Since a dictionary with m keys is created (where m is the number of unique values in `inp_list`, the space complexity is O(n+m) < O(2n) = O(n)

Comment: `O(n+m)` will be `O(n)`

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction, I added this to the answer

Comment: While `O(n*m)` is technically correct as an upper bound, it's even higher than OP's existing overestimate. The best upper bound possible is `O(n)`; I think that is a more helpful bound.

Comment: If `d` were a list then this was indeed the bound but `d` is actually a dictionary and the key search takes O(1) due to the hashing, I corrected the answer, thank you

Comment: [Benchmark](https://tio.run/##fZHdaoQwEIXv8xRzs2xSRCpSKIV9hb6ASEh1bFPMD0kE25e3iXGrpe3mSnPOnG9mYj/Cm9H1o3XLMjijIEiFMoBU1rgADi2KQEiPA7xPPnBhLeqesicC8Qi4QNOun4NxMIPUMPusrXq5@We23jkMk9MgcqCxESY/sf8/NQvx/5p0g3WDZB2KcTSdCPgD8mw0tnAHI2o6e/YdLgsQjWwTAvWk0KXCaNhpVnj/B2iUcUedUfaK2eRmPjbdEjL7yE9u6oR@RVrdr4cxknw8@bJQb0Hpeph0l5TDSxS/tlgcpy32jvbeQ0QrqWl@XJpSC4hjvqC7VIztMzqpAz2fHspqAOXhDCegIa6rwpoVazcl51oo5DxX5Qq2LF8) of append vs preallocate. Let me know if you can optimize the preallocate to make it faster than any of the alternatives :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy I did the changes in the code and ran a `%%timeit`, added the results to the answer :). I agree, this was not the improvement I was looking for but it is not neglectable

Comment: That's a very special case, m very small compared to n. Also, it's not faster because of the preallocation but because you use list operations done in C rather than the original Python loop. Try yours but without preallocation and instead `append` and `+=` (or `extend`), that'll likely be even faster. And better use Python ints instead of NumPy ints.

Comment: I tried and You were right, I stand myself corrected. Removed this section